# Jcarousel jumps to near end of next image and slides like it should to the next image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I have a weird problem with jCarousel where, when hard refreshed in firefox or ie 8, it delays and then animates the last part of the image. In other words, it's like the image nearly jumps to the end of the next image and then slides the last bit like it should. A link to the page is www.flooringdepot.co.za . If you hard refresh in ie 8 or firefox, you should see what I mean with the carousel.

Comment: I have solved this issue and is no longer a problem because I used different code